# Jenkins buid when active sprint complete in JIRA

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jira, sprint

Is it possible trigger to Jenkins build a job when the jira active sprint is complete?

Comment: Jira Server/DC (on-premise) or Jira Cloud?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.